# How can I display a sucess message after person pressed submitted a form in bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a prototype of a site and i am trying to make it look like a person submitting a form for receiving their information in a bootstrap modal thingy.

I have this log in at the top of my page:

```
<div class="center-top-div">

        <form class="well inline-form" action="sidor/my_page.html" method="">
            <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" class="span2" placeholder="Password">
            <a href="sidor/index_inloggad.html" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" id="logga-in-btn">Log in</a><br>
            <a class="pull-right" id="amnesi" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Forgotten?</a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

When one would press on the link "Forgotten?" a modal will be shown:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
           <h4 id="myModalLabel">Vi behöver din E-postadress!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="well inline-form larger-input">
                 <input class="input-large" type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Din E-postadress...">
                 <a href="//I WANT THIS TO LINK TO ANOTHER MODAL/GREETING MESSAGE" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" 
                    id="logga-in-btn">Get my details!</a><br>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

What i want to happen is, when a person clicks on "Get my details!" I would like to display a greeting message or something, in the modal or another modal.

Any ideas will be appreciated! :)

/Bill

Comment: You want a modal inside a modal to show the details?

Comment: To show, "Thank you, we have now email you your details" or something like that :)

Comment: I just want to display a nice greeting message after a person "submitted" (this is only a prototype) for receiving their details.

Comment: see if this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for any click events to happes. See if this satisfies your need. This will display the message in the modal itself.

**http://jsfiddle.net/spaXZ/**

```
    $('body').on('click','#logga-in-btn' ,function(){
    $(this).closest('.modal-body').find('#grtmessage').remove().end().append($('<span id="grtmessage">Thank you, we have now email you your details</span>'));
});
```

if you want to display as modal you may try this:- **http://jsfiddle.net/HxrHd/**

Comment: Thank you once again @PSCoder! Your example, "display as modal", was exactly what i wanted to achieve! Many thanks!